# How to create a new Graph in virtuoso using Jena and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, sparql, jena, virtuoso

Hi i am trying to create a graph with a particular name in virtuoso with the help of jena in java spring boot, i cant find any example or article online to do that, can anyone please help.
I am able to clear and add data to an existing graph but in my current implementation i need to create a graph with a particular name first and then upload a ttl file.
If anyone can provide me with a working example it will be helpful.

Comment: why would you need to create the graph first? This isn't necessary when you load data into a graph, this graph will be create if not existing already. Otherwise, use SPARQL Update if you really think you need to create it in advance: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#create

Comment: SPARQL Graph Store Protocol:: `GSP.service("http://server/../sparql-graph-crud/").graphName("http://..graphname..").POST(filename);`

Comment: @UninformedUser i was not aware it works like that , i am kinda new to virtuoso and graph stores and yeah the graph is created automatically so this worked for me, thank you!!

Comment: @AndyS i understand the impementation you are referring to but i planned not to use HTTP calls at all to the virtuoso server because of my own organizational needs, still thank you for the help